# Heroku: Cannot push to Heroku due to gem install bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, bundler

All of a sudden I cannot push to Heroku and I get to the point where the build has succeeded, but then on compilation I see the following:

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: sh: 1: gem-install-bundler: not found
remote: sh: 1: gem-install-bundler: not found
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.2.3-The-latest-bundler-is-1.15.2,-but-you-are-currently-running-1.15.1.-To-update,-run-`gem-install-bundler`
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !     
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.2.3-The-latest-bundler-is-1.15.2,-but-you-are-currently-running-1.15.1.-To-update,-run-`gem-install-bundler`.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     bash: gem-install-bundler: command not found
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

From what I could gather, I figured I needed to update bundler, so I updated bundler to version 1.15.2, and attempted to push it up again, but the same error is shown.  My `gemfile.lock` even says `BUNDLED WITH 1.15.2`.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Which Heroku stack are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to Heroku and they showed me that I had multiple buildpacks:

> Thanks for contacting us regarding issue around installation of ruby.
>   It seems that the app has Heroku Buildpack for Ruby specified twice,
>   with the latter specifying the master version rather than the released
>   version:

```
$ heroku buildpacks -a app-name
=== app-name Buildpack URLs
1. heroku/ruby
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
3. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

They then continued to show me how to solve the issue:

> Could you please try specifying each of buildpacks once as well as
>   using the released versions to see if the problem pertists?

```
$ heroku buildpacks:remove -i 3 -a app-name
$ heroku buildpacks:remove -i 2 -a app-name
$ heroku buildpacks:remove -i 1 -a app-name
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs -a app-name
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby -a app-name
$ git push heroku master
```

and this solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

did you Check the resulting Gemfile.lock into version control

```
git add Gemfile.lock
```